# Using jQuery to replace an option element in one select box with another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes, one of which is dynamically populated. The second box I would like to replace the option element with whatever is selected. At the moment, I have it working with this:

```
    var currentManCodeSelected = $('#sltmanu').find(':selected')[i].value;
    var currentManCodeName = $('#sltmanu').find(':selected')[i].text;

    $('#sltmanuCurrent option:first').replaceWith("<option value='" + currentManCodeSelected + "'>" + currentManCodeName + "</option>");
```

Is there a better way of doing this? A shorter and more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like following;

**HTML:**

```
<select id="left">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<select id="right">
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
    <option value="f">f</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").on('change', function() {
        $('#right :selected').val($('#left :selected').val()).text($('#left :selected').text());
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Azugu/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value and text instead of replacing the whole element

```
$('#sltmanuCurrent option:first').val(currentManCodeSelected).text(currentManCodeName);
```